# Can the Weblogic default handler display the list of contexts?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

In Jetty, if there is no deployment at '/' then the [DefaultHandler](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/jetty-6/xref/org/mortbay/jetty/handler/DefaultHandler.html) displays a list of known contexts. This is very useful during development.

Is it possible to configure BEA Weblogic to provide a similar convenience?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small webapp that hooks up to the `Weblogic JMX` and displays the list of deployed webapps and deploy that one at '/'.